# How to connect an app with ONLY String {userName} and String {Password} (no email)?

Tags: android, database, android-studio, backendless, nosql

I was wondering if there is any chance some one could help me with a registery.
Problem is I can't fined a way to connect the app to Backendless (well I can connect it but it make problems) Because I have to use a String userName and not a String email.
The "@" sign is killing my app because I am using 2 different databases (noSQL and Backendless).
Is there a way or Backendless is only bout email and password?!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the identity field from "email" to your custom "userName" column on Users tab -> User Properties.

Comment: Thank You I made it, *Property("user", txtUser.getText().toString()).